# Issue with form validation Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using Bootstrap and I have two identical forms. I am trying to add form submission to Google Search results and it works but when I include two of the same form it doesn't work because of the id being the same on both. How can I fix this? The ID needs to be the same because google looks for the "G". The reason I have two forms is because I have it displayed differently on mobile. Using media queries. Below is my code thanks.

```
<form name="globalSearch" class="navbar-form" role="search" form action="" onsubmit="return validateSearch()">
        <div class="input-group add-on">
          <input type="hidden" name="cx" value="" />
          <input type="hidden" name="cof" value="FORID:11;NB:1" />
          <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8" />
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search entire site..." id="q" name="q" type="text">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default btnSubmit" type="submit">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
</form>

function validateSearch() {
        if (globalSearch.q.value.length == 0) {
            document.getElementById("q").value = "Enter a Value";
            document.getElementById("q").style.color = "red";
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is bad practice to have repeated ids on a single page. Use different ids and keep the same name.

Comment: that "q" is necessary for google. i cant change it

Comment: Are you sure it is necessary in the ID and not just in the NAME attribute??? As I can see from google.com search page they just use the name attribute and a custom id.

Comment: note: the syntax `globalSearch.q.value.length` gets the element by its name, not id

Comment: why two form!!, you can style the same form for mobile devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to change the placeholder, so the user don't have to delete the text than type in a query. Please view updated function.

```
function validateSearch() {
  var q = document.getElementById('q');
  if (q.value.length == 0) {
    q.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Enter search term')
    q.style.borderColor = "red";
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two elements can not share same ID.
Either use CSS styling to make different looks in mobile, either hide one of forms from webserver (PHP/etc) side either dont use getElementById - instead, use jQuery:

```
<form name="globalSearch" ... >
<input name="q" data-input-type="desktop" id="q">
..
</form>
<script>
 function validateSearch() {

     var field = $("input[data-input-type="desktop"]');
     field.val("Enter value here...");
     field.css("color","red");
 }
 </script>
```